# Passenger crashes, hangs at apache start

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, ubuntu, passenger

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu, with Ruby/Rails/RVM with Apache via Passenger, apache will come up on a clean reboot, but crash at the first request to the Rails app.

I have done all of this many times before ... except RVM installed in multi-user mode.

It seems like maybe there's some library conflict?

Details below.

- 64-bit Ubuntu 11.10 installation
- created a release user, and group
- uninstall the default apache, ruby, passenger (sudo apt-get remove ...)
- installed RVM using the system version (multiple users)
- installed ruby 1.9.3p194 using RVM (installed as the release user)
- add release user to group `rvm`
- ruby and gems are under /usr/local/rvm/ and are all in group `rvm` and readable
- install apache2 and various supporting libraries (`sudo apt-get install apache2`)
- add apache2 user (`www-data`) to group `rvm`
- install passenger from gem (`gem install passenger`)
- use passenger to make passenger module (`passenger-install-apache2-module`). No errors.
- configure apache to load the correct module (under /usr/local/rvm...)
- configure apache to reference the correct PassengerRoot and PassengerRuby
- note: this is all without any reference to the Rails app
- start apache (`sudo apache2ctl start`) ... this hangs

Apache error.log shows

```
[ pid=1303 thr=140033289561952 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:1389 time=2012-05-07 19:54:15.497 ]: Initializing Phusion Passenger...
[ pid=1303 thr=140033289561952 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:1664 time=2012-05-07 19:54:15.536 ]: Shutting down Phusion Passenger...
[ pid=1312 thr=140533444790112 file=ext/common/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:283 time=2012-05-07 19:54:15.537 ]: Logging agent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.1303/generation-0/logging.socket
```

In other words, passenger terminates moments after it starts.  `/var/log/syslog` shows a stack dump for PassengerWatchd.

I tried running passenger in standalone mode.  Nada.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking, this ended up being an issue for several people, and there are several good workarounds posted on the [Passenger Google Group here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/phusion-passenger/RWgxl6sRycY/discussion)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your passenger.conf is using the same version of ruby as in your console.

```
$ cat /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf 
PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
PassengerRoot /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/passenger-3.0.18
PassengerDefaultUser www-data
```

Compare the PassengerRuby is the same as:

```
$ which ruby
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby
```